# vpn, в Беларуси отключили интернет

Tags: vpn

В Беларуси из-за выборов отключили в стране интернет, помогает vpn в браузере. Но в самой системе не работает, например npm и вообще все. Посоветуйте нормальные vpn. Система - macos.

Comment: [ProtonVPN](https://protonvpn.com/) - Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android, iOS.

Comment: А просто дебильный OpenVPN до своего VPS где-нибудь на Digital Ocean? Пять долларов в месяц — и никто, вообще никто не подсмотрит трафик.

Comment: ProtonVPN - не работает, я проверял.

Comment: Alexander Prokoshev можно поподробнее?

Comment: Использую [EncryptMe](http://encrypt.me).

Comment: Установил, идет установка соединения, но так и не работает.

Comment: Короче говоря,  EncryptMe не работает.

Comment: @PROCODE не работает, у Вас.

Comment: @IgorR. Вы тоже из Беларуси?

Comment: GoodbyeDPI - проверил, вроде только для windows, а у меня mac.

Comment: https://www.psiphon3.com/ru/index.html может помочь. На windows /android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте [IPVanish](https://www.ipvanish.com/) - работал у меня во всех зверских странах.

В Беларуссии тоже должен работать, правда он платный, но зато хороший.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте X VPN. [Вот ссылка в App Store.](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/x-vpn-fast-stable-vpn-proxy/id1454212375?mt=12)

Comment: Нет, подключается, пишет On, но когда пытаюсь зайти в интернет, не работает.

Comment: Ну тогда простите, ничем не могу помочь(